# C# Filtrar Row Json en DataGridView para mostrar solo 1 o 2 lineas segun seleccion

Tags: c#

estoy intentando crear un filtro para una columna en concreto de mi datagridview que consume los datos mediante un json.

Mi idea es que sea un filtro de una columna "Name" que tengas la posibilidad de seleccionar que quieres ver en el datagridview. Es decir si selecciono un valor de esa columna del filtro solo me muestra la linea de row seleccionada segun el filtro o si selecciono 2 valores que me llegan en 2 filas que solo muestre esas dos filas de row y las demas esten ocultas, no ocultar columnas eso ya lo tengo creado con checkbox.

Alguien se le ocurre alguna idea o me puede echar una mano con esto? no se como hacer esto ahora mismo no se me ocurre alguna logica.

Aqui os dejo codigo que manejo para un datagridview con un timer para actualizar los datos de la tabla cada 1 segundo consultando una url que contiene un .json

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick()
        {
            
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = (1 * 1000); //Time Refresh Table
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
            timer.Start();
        }

        private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            string url = "http://192.168.1.10/data.json";
            var json = wc.DownloadString(new Uri(url));
            
            List<Socket1> socket1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Socket1>>(json);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = socket1;
            this.dataGridView1.Columns["ID"].Visible = false;
            this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Selected = false;
            }
```

Comment: Ahora mismo despues de escribir el post se me ocurre algo con esto this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Selected = false;   pero con Visible.
Jugar con esto y el foreach con el if and else con checkbox pero claro eso seria un para mi como si hardcodeas algo, voy a seguir tambien informandome mas de datagridview sobre filtros en lo que alguien me puede echar una mano y aportarme alguna luz que me de alguna idea o algo de info mas especifica de filtro para datagridview porque encuentro mucho para datatable. Gracias y perdonas por esta chapa.